# Give LL grammar for this language?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I need to give the LL grammar for the language below and explain why the grammar is LL and what the value of $k$ should be:

$$L = \{ a^n c^m c^{n+m} : n \ge 1, m \ge 1 \}. $$

I have the following, but it works for $n \ge 0$ and $m \ge 0$. I'm not sure how to get rid of that case where $n$ and $m$ are 0.

$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to aSc \mid Z \mid \lambda \\
&Z \to bZc \mid \lambda
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Do you mean $a^nb^mc^{n+m}$? And do you denote by $\lambda$ the empty string?